# Woocommerce get sub order number in multi vendor orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dokan

I'm using woocommerce and dokan plugin in wordpress.
After I try to order product in multi vendor, I get the sub order number in thank you page.
I try to get sub order number by running this code below but not work.

```
//example order id
$order = wc_get_order(1234);

$order_id = $order->get_id();

$sub_orders = get_children( 
   array(    
     'post_parent' => $order_id,    
     'post_type'   => 'shop_order',    
     'post_status' => array( 
        'wc-pending', 
        'wc-completed', 
        'wc-processing', 
        'wc-on-hold' 
       )
   ) 
);
```

when i try `var_dump($sub_order)` i got 0 array result.
is any way to get sub order?

Answer (score 1):

I found this function in plugin:

```
/**
 * 
 * @global object $wpdb
 * @param type $parent_order_id
 * @return type
 */
function dokan_get_suborder_ids_by ($parent_order_id){
    
    global $wpdb;
     
     $sql = "SELECT ID FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts
             WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
             AND post_parent = " . $parent_order_id;
     
     $sub_orders = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    if ( ! $sub_orders ) {
        return null;
    }
    
    return $sub_orders;
```

I think you can use her for getting sub orders, for example:

```
$order = wc_get_order(1234);

$order_id = $order->get_id();

$sub_orders = dokan_get_suborder_ids_by($order_id);

foreach($sub_orders as $sub_order) {
    $child_order = wc_get_order($sub_order);
    var_dump($child_order);
}
```

Hope help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$parent_order = wc_get_order(1234);

$sub_orders = get_children([
    'post_parent' => dokan_get_prop( $parent_order, 'id' ),
    'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
]);
```

Note that if the parent order contains products only from one vendor your `$sub_orders` variable will be empty.